# What is the difference between int (*p)[10]=s and int (*o)[5]=&s?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, pointer-to-array

On basis of the convention int (*o)[5]=&s; is the right way for a pointer o to point an array having 5 elements.

We can also write this s in this statement

```
int (*p)[10]=s;
```

but why preferring

```
&s at int (*o)[5]=&s;
```

as both of them return the same output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int s[5]={10,1,2,3,4};
        int (*p)[10]=s;
        printf("%d\n",*p);
        printf("%d\n",**p);
        printf("%d\n",&s);
        
        printf("\n");

        int (*o)[5]=&s;
        printf("%d\n",*o);
        printf("%d\n",**o);
        printf("%d",&s);
    
        return 0;
}
```

Output of this program is:

```
-593812272
10
-593812272

-593812272
10
-593812272
```

Comment: A decent compiler should generate a warning for `int (*p)[10]=s;`:
` warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int (*)[5]' with an expression of type 'int [5]'; take the address with & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
int (*p)[10]=s;
```

is incorrect. The initializer has the type `int *` due to the implicit conversion of the array designator `s` to a pointer to its first element. And the two pointers in the left hand side and in the right hand are not compatible. So the compiler should issue a message.

This line

```
int (*o)[5]=&s;
```

is correct. The initializer has the type `int ( * )[5]` that is the same type of the initialized pointer `o`.

Pay attention to that to output a value of a pointer you have to use the conversion specifier `%p`. Otherwise using the conversion specifier `%d` to output a pointer invokes undefined behavior.

So for example instead of these calls

```
printf("%d\n",*o);
//...
printf("%d",&s);
```

you have to write

```
printf("%p\n", ( void *)*o);
//...
printf("%p\n", ( void * )&s);
```

The expression `*o` yields value of the array `s` that is in turn is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

The values of the expression `*o` and of the expression `&s` are the same because it is the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array. But their types are different. The first expression used as an argument of the call of `printf` has the type `int *` while the second expression has the type `int ( * )[5]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid:

```
    int s[5]={10,1,2,3,4};
    int (*p)[10]=s;
```

Because you're initializing a variable of type `int (*)[10]` (a pointer to an array of `int` of size 10) with an expression of type `int *`.  These types are not compatible.

While this is fine:

```
    int (*o)[5]=&s;
```

Because the type of the initializer matches the type of the variable.

Also, when printing pointer values, you should use the `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `void *`.  Mismatching format specifiers with their associated arguments triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).